# Where are the logs for UFW located on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, logs, ufw

UFW is enabled and logging is set to HIGH on my Arch Linux system. I am sure that it is running and blocking some of my connection attempts. However I cannot find any logs. The places/commands I tried to check:

- `journalctl -u ufw`
- `journalctl | grep ufw`
- `/var/log/ufw*` (not found)
- `/var/log/messages` (not found)
- `/var/log/syslog` (not found)
- `/var/log/kern.log` (not found)

Where are the logs for UFW located on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is no additional logger configured, all UFW events should be logged to systemd journal by default.

UFW entries have the following format:

```
Sep 13 21:52:11 xps kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp58s0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.103 DST=192.168.1.209 LEN=545 TOS=0x00 PREC
Sep 13 21:52:12 xps kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp58s0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.103 DST=192.168.1.209 LEN=545 TOS=0x00 PREC
Sep 13 21:52:13 xps kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp58s0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.1.103 DST=192.168.1.209 LEN=545 TOS=0x00 PREC
```

Try `journalctl | grep -i ufw` to search for all UFW entries regardless letter case.

Comment: This case is indeed a letter case. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason that this isn't categorized as a unit? `journalctl -u ufw` is much more intuitive, it seems strange that it's not logging there.

Comment: @Nathan You are right, in fact ufw is categorized as a unit (at least now it is), so `journalctl -u ufw` is the best solution.

I just tried to fix the example with grep that had been posted in original question.

Comment: @zoresvit I meant that `journalctl -u ufw` doesn't appear to work (at least on my machine), but the grep solution does. `journalctl -u ufw` gives me a short log of the startup/stopping of the unit, but doesn't give an actual verbose log-- and I was curious if you knew why that was.

Comment: @Nathan Oh, I didn't notice that — I don't use it normally, so didn't see much difference in the output.