# Make ufw log without rsyslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, logs, firewall

I have no ufw logs on my minimized Ubuntu 22.04 server.

sudo ufw status verbose output:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
```

On the internet I found I need rsyslogd enabled. On Ubuntu 22.04 minimzed rsyslog is not installed by default and I want to keep it like that.

How can make ufw to log correctly without installing rsyslog?

Comment: Have you tried using `journalctl`? Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309733/414186)